# Expo Location Error: Not authorized to use background location services

Tags: typescript, react-native, location, expo

I'm creating a app that needs the current location of the user and need to run in real time. i'm using the Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync() from expo but i'm getting the error below.
The app.json is already configured and in the phone i accept the location permission. someone can tell me why i'm getting the error?

app.json

```
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.ourtor.ourtorapp",
      "buildNumber": "0.0.8",
     "infoPlist": { "UIBackgroundModes": [ "location", "fetch" ] }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
      ]
    },
```

map.ts

```
  useEffect( () => {

    Location.requestPermissionsAsync().then( async (res) => {
      if(res.status === "granted") {
        console.log('granted')
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('get-location', {
          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced
        })
      }
      
    });
    
  }, [])
```

console android

```
granted
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Not authorized to use background location services.]
```

console ios

```
granted
Background Location has not been configured. To enable it, add 'location' to 'UIBackgroundModes' in Info.plist file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need *background* location? Seems that configuring Location for *background* use is a lot more work. The configuration matrix for Location is complex (Android, Apple, Emulators, Permissions, Foreground\Background, and even an app submission request for Android). I would make sure you've thoroughly read Expo's documentation because all these details are scattered throughout the page: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#background-location-methods

That said, I had a similar issue for getting the Location while the app was in the *foreground* on Android. I had to make sure Location was turned on for Expo Go in the Android app settings. That was not enough though, the call to Location.getPermissionAsync() was required (it was not on my Apple device). Then I was able to use Location.watchPositionAsync(...) without issue.

One other thing I'll mention, your question popped up when there was a larger issue with Location in Expo Go (at the time it was still Expo Client). You can see this GitHub issue for more detail: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11330. TLDR; if you're on Expo Go > 2.18.5 you shouldn't be seeing this issue anymore.

Answer (score -1):

There is a better way to do this susing expo permissions
for more infomation take a look at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/

Comment: I've already tried this way and not worked